# Spring Localization with html

Tags: html, spring, localization, internationalization, spring-security

I have created a spring application with multiple language support, using spring localization/Internationalization and jstl. Now I am going to remove all the jsp and replace it with html. Can make use of spring localization/Internationalization and resource bundles in pure html without jstl? (I am sure there has to be a way.)

Comment: A browser can understand only HTML,but a servlet container need class file to process and generate HTML. I am not sure why you want to remove JSP,JSTL etc because they aim to generate HTML in the end..

Comment: I am supposed to move to a single page application model. And in the end I will need to use java script only and make Ajax requests as and when needed. Also I want to design such that my front end should never be dependent on my backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of JSTL if that's what you are asking for. After all, Spring has its own `<sp:message>` tag.

However, if you want to get rid of JSP completely and only serve static HTML, I am afraid it can't be done *correctly*.
That is, you can possibly generate the whole page with JavaScript (i.e. jQuery), but how useful is that?
And you'll be forced to implement some means of Localization for JavaScript anyway. I mean you'll probably need to generate file with translations on-the-fly.
It's do-able, but it would be extremely easy to introduce for example concatenation defects (that won't allow for re-ordering the sentence, that is proper translations).

To summarize this: you probably can do that, but you probably should not.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible..with minimum tweaks..
Dont remove jSP,JSTL etc..
Convert each submit request to ajax..A server doesnt care whether a request is a normal browser submit request or XMLHttpRequest(ajax)..server will use JSP,JSTL to prepare appropriate HTML..u need ajax to render that html string into DOM.

```
$.ajax(url:'/xyz',
       success:function(htmlFromServer){

document.open();
document.write(htmlFromServer);
document.close();
});
```